# Retain element size and position when zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I retain an elements default size when a browser is zoomed in. My goal
is to retain an elements default size and position, no matter how many percentages the users has zoomed in or out.

I have encountered a few useful css properties, transform scale and transform-origin, but I haven't been able to achieve my goal. The scale doesn't match up with the zoom level.

Can someone give me some pointers.

```
var defaultScale = 1.0;
var zoomLevel = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
var scale = defaultScale - (zoomLevel - defaultScale);

$('.popup-overlay').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
```

Comment: So basically you want to keep the user from zooming. Why?

Comment: So if I am visually impaired, you're going to try to prevent me from reading the text on your site if I zoom in. Really?

Comment: I really hope this ain't possible. Such an idea is evil.

Comment: I'm only planning to scale fullscreen popup-overlay elements. If a users has zommed in, and a fullscreen popup-overlay appears, it should be shown as if the zoom level was at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

When the popup appears, you could measure the width of the browser window, and the popup, then do some math to set the popup's percentage width to the screen. The percentage should be maintained when zoomed.

```
var popwidth = $('.popup-overlay').width();
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var popercentage = (parseInt(popwidth)/parseInt(windowWidth))*100;
$('.popup-overlay').css('width',popercentage+'%');
```